# upgrading power sequencer on Cisco 5548UP Switch

Tags: cisco

The situation is that i've 5548UP Switch with very old software version:

```
Software
BIOS: version 3.6.0
loader: version N/A
kickstart: version 7.0(5)N1(1)
system: version 7.0(5)N1(1)
Power Sequencer Firmware:
Module 1: version v1.0
Module 2: version v0.0
Module 3: version v5.0
Microcontroller Firmware: version v1.2.0.1
SFP uC: Module 1: v1.0.0.0
QSFP uC: Module not detected
BIOS compile time: 05/09/2012
kickstart image file is: bootflash:///n5000-uk9-kickstart.7.0.5.N1.1.bin
kickstart compile time: 10/29/2014 22:00:00 [10/30/2014 07:30:37]
system image file is: bootflash:///n5000-uk9.7.0.5.N1.1.bin
system compile time: 10/29/2014 22:00:00 [10/30/2014 12:45:59
```

I don't know how it happened but seems like this switch **power sequencer version is older than it should be by existing 7.0(5)N1(1)**. I know that because other switch in a pair has newer Power sequencer version with the same software version. I think it could by because someone installed this device in a wrong way - for example not with install all, but with setting the boot variables and restarting the switch.

So, i have googled the right path to upgrade the software, the next step will be version 7.1.4.N1.1, and by doing show install all impact I see:

```
Module             Image         Running-Version             New-Version  Upg-Required
------  ----------------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ------------
     1            system             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.1(4)N1(1)           yes
     1         kickstart             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.1(4)N1(1)           yes
     1              bios      v3.6.0(05/09/2012)      v3.6.0(05/09/2012)            no
     1         power-seq                    v1.0                    v3.0           yes
     1            SFP-uC                v1.0.0.0                v1.0.0.0            no
     2         power-seq                    v0.0                    v1.0           yes
     3         power-seq                    v5.0                    v5.0            no
   103             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.1(4)N1(1)           yes
   104             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.1(4)N1(1)           yes
   155             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.1(4)N1(1)           yes
     1   microcontroller                v1.2.0.1                v1.2.0.1            no
```

So by looking at this everything should be ok, i will upgrade the switch, after that i will do the reload with power-cycle option.

Is there anything i should take into action more ? It's some type of not ordinary situation because the current software (i guess) was installed not in the right way. Or maybe i would need to reinstall the current  one 7.0(5)N1(1) ?

show version output from correctly installed switch:

```
  BIOS:      version 3.6.0
  loader:    version N/A
  kickstart: version 7.0(5)N1(1)
  system:    version 7.0(5)N1(1)
  Power Sequencer Firmware: 
             **Module 1: version v3.0**
             **Module 2: version v1.0**
             Module 3: version v5.0
  Microcontroller Firmware:        version v1.2.0.1
  SFP uC:    Module 1: v1.0.0.0
  QSFP uC:   Module not detected
```

show install impact when reinstalling switch:

```
Verifying image bootflash:/n5000-uk9-kickstart.7.0.5.N1.1.bin for boot variable "kickstart".
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Verifying image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.7.0.5.N1.1.bin for boot variable "system".
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Verifying image type.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Extracting "system" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.7.0.5.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Extracting "kickstart" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9-kickstart.7.0.5.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Extracting "bios" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.7.0.5.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Extracting "fexth" version from image bootflash:/n5000-uk9.7.0.5.N1.1.bin.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Performing module support checks.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS

Notifying services about system upgrade.
[####################] 100% -- SUCCESS



Compatibility check is done:
Module  bootable          Impact  Install-type  Reason
------  --------  --------------  ------------  ------
     1       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
     2       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
     3       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   103       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   104       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   106       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   109       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   110       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   113       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   126       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   128       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   129       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   130       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   134       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   150       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   151       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   154       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive
   155       yes      disruptive         reset  LC is disruptive



Images will be upgraded according to following table:
Module             Image         Running-Version             New-Version  Upg-Required
------  ----------------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ------------
     1            system             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
     1         kickstart             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
     1              bios      v3.6.0(05/09/2012)      v3.6.0(05/09/2012)            no
     1         power-seq                    v1.0                    v3.0           yes
     1            SFP-uC                v1.0.0.0                v1.0.0.0            no
     2         power-seq                    v0.0                    v1.0           yes
     3         power-seq                    v5.0                    v5.0            no
   103             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   104             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   106             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   109             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   110             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   113             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   126             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   128             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   129             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   130             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   134             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   150             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   151             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   154             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
   155             fexth             7.0(5)N1(1)             7.0(5)N1(1)            no
     1   microcontroller                v1.2.0.1                v1.2.0.1            no


Additional info for this installation:
--------------------------------------
Remove QoS & ACL config on L3 interfaces and SVIs if any

Service "stp" : Port: port-channel124 in VLAN0001 is Designated. Topology change could occur during ISSU.
Upgrade needs to be disruptive!!!

Service "lacp" : LACP: Upgrade will be disruptive as 0 switch ports and 131 fex ports are not upgrade ready!!

Service "vpc" : STP Preupgrade Check failed on VPC peer switch
```

Comment: Not that I can think of.  It's a pretty straightforward procedure.  I wouldn't stop at 7.1(4)N1(1), though.  That's crazy old, and is full of bugs that have been addressed in later releases..

Comment: thanks for reply. 7.1.4.N1.1 is just an interim step. After that it will be the latest recommended. The main question was what to do with the current - wrongly installted (7.0.5.N1) version. Option 1 > proceed further Options 2> reinstall 7.0.5N.1 correctly and then proceed further.

Comment: Can you provide the output from the other switch you say is running the same release but has a newer power sequence version? If you want to be sure that the upgrade to the next release/step goes smoothly, I would reinstall 7.0(5)N1(1) to let it upgrade the various pieces correctly. If not, you run the risk of making your job a lot harder trying to fix things (probably requiring a downgrade or call to Cisco TAC).

Comment: thanks again for reply. I added the show version from correctly installed switch. As you see the power sequencer versions are newer. I think i will do the safe approach and will reinstall correctly (via install all) that wrongly installed switch. Though, it will be the first time i will be reinstalling the existing version. :)

Comment: Sounds like a smart move. I've never had to reinstall the same version on top of itself but I have had to downgrade before, due to a bug in a newer release that cause the Nexus 2K units to become unstable.

Comment: thanks, today tried to do show install all impact with the current software i see strange new thing; Service "vpc" : STP Preupgrade Check failed on VPC peer switch. Wondering what does that mean. Any clue ?

Comment: Run the command `show spanning-tree issu-impact` and see what the output says the problem is.

Comment: thanks, i see lots of port-channels. https://pastebin.com/fZC3tHQs some of them are not in VPC mode - because connected to other switches or they're uplinks. I think thats not a big problem because the upgrade will be done in maintenance mode. So minimal disruption is OK. Also, i haven't see anywhere "LC is disruptive" message during compatibility check. but i think its not a big problem:)

Comment: Are your configs matched between the 2 switches as they should be for being in a VPC peering? If not, like if there's a port channel missing on one side, that could be a problem.

Comment: the strange thing that show vpc on that port-channels shows that VPC is OK. If it's a problem just for ISSU - it should not matter, because we're doing it disruptively..

Comment: Have you tried using `show vpc consistency-parameters global` to see if everything is matched correctly?

Comment: i've pruned some unused vlans (via trunk allowed vlan) command now issu impact showsonly about 20 items. All of them are interfaces connected to other switches. So i think this makes sense ? The output is here: https://pastebin.com/xnuRPzUJ

Comment: You should be fine as long as you can do a disruptive install.  My Nexus 5ks show the same failure on Criteria 3, and I've had no issues beside that one buggy software version I mentioned previously. Just make sure you have current config backups to be on the safe side.

Comment: thanks for so much info. definetely the cfg is backuped, we have some remote console access too. The last thing is on first post the reason stated id "LC is disruptive" i've never seen that reason. Even tried to google - no information. This is the only thing where i'm consused:). The newer software shows some other reason. Do you know what the LC stands for ? Thanks :)

Comment: Line Card. Do you have some kind of expansion module in your chassis?

Comment: yes, we've installed a line card of 16ports. Thanks. Strange that i see quite different message when doing show install impact with newer versions. Anyhow - i guess it could be that the message is provided by particular image file..

Comment: How did the upgrade go?

Comment: thanks, it's still pending. There occurred some issues to plan the maintenance window.. will inform you after the maintenance will be done!

Comment: Oh. Okay.  I was just wondering.

Comment: managed to do it yesterday. So we took approach to skip reinstalling the same version. Moved straight to installing interim version and the final one. Everything was upgraded smoothly. Few interfaces after upgrade got down. Managed to fix one by changing the SFP. Other one is left in very strange state called `HARDWARE FAILURE`. Tried to swap SFPS in both ends - it doesnt help. This is not very big problem, but interesting one. So, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to do it yesterday. So we took approach to skip reinstalling the same version. Moved straight to installing interim version and the final one. After the install of interim version i did additional `reload power-cycle` because of power-sequencers upgrade. Everything was upgraded smoothly. Few interfaces after upgrade got down. Managed to fix one by changing the SFP. Other one is left in very strange state called `HARDWARE FAILURE`. Tried to swap SFPs in both ends - it doesnt help. This is not very big problem, but interesting one.

Comment: Nice.  Glad the upgrades fixed your main problem.  Do the logs show anything about this one interface that might be more helpful? Have you opened a Cisco TAC case?

Comment: sad thing , that we dont have support. i got advice on cisco forum to run show diagnostic command. `show diagnostic result module all` indicates letter F which means - that the interface is failed. Someone advised to try to turn off all the 32 interface module, and turn on again. But we just cant allow for ourself to make this test.. So for now - i think we will live with that Failed port..

Comment: Not to get you in trouble or anything but, how did you get the software image if you don't have an active support contract?

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Jesse, we're getting that via from our partners.